# Add webparts on publishing page with Visual Studio

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

While creating a new publishing site I would like to add the shared documents webpart on the default page. I've read a lot of documentation, but haven't found any answer yet.

This is the ONET.xml file

```
<Project Title="$Resources:onet_TeamWebSite;" Revision="2" ListDir="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" UIVersion="4">
  <NavBars>
   </NavBars>

  <Configurations>
    <Configuration ID="0" Name="Blank" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master">
      <Modules>
        <Module Name="DefaultBlank" />
      </Modules>
      <Lists>
        <List FeatureId="00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101" Type="101" Title="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Title;" Url="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Folder;" />
        <List FeatureId="00BFEA71-6A49-43FA-B535-D15C05500108" Type="108" Title="$Resources:core,discussions_Title;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,discussions_Folder;" QuickLaunchUrl="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,discussions_Folder;" />
        <List FeatureId="00BFEA71-D1CE-42de-9C63-A44004CE0104" Type="104" Title="$Resources:core,announceList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;">
          <Data>
            <Rows>
              <Row>
                <Field Name="Title">$Resources:onetid11;</Field>
                <Field Name="Body">$Resources:onetid12;</Field>
                <Field Name="Expires">&lt;ows:TodayISO/&gt;</Field>
              </Row>
            </Rows>
          </Data>
        </List>
        <List FeatureId="00BFEA71-2062-426C-90BF-714C59600103" Type="103" Title="$Resources:core,linksList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,links_Folder;" />
        <List FeatureId="00BFEA71-EC85-4903-972D-EBE475780106" Type="106" Title="$Resources:core,calendarList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder;" QuickLaunchUrl="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder;/Calendar.aspx" />
        <List FeatureId="00BFEA71-A83E-497E-9BA0-7A5C597D0107" Type="107" Title="$Resources:core,taskList;" Url="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,tasks_Folder;" />
      </Lists>


      <SiteFeatures>

        <!-- BasicWebParts Feature -->
        <Feature ID="00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57" />

        <!-- Three-state Workflow Feature -->
        <Feature ID="FDE5D850-671E-4143-950A-87B473922DC7" />

        <!--  Site collection Publish features -->
        <Feature ID="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" />

      </SiteFeatures>
      <WebFeatures>

        <!-- TeamCollab Feature -->
        <Feature ID="00BFEA71-4EA5-48D4-A4AD-7EA5C011ABE5" />

        <!-- MobilityRedirect -->
        <Feature ID="F41CC668-37E5-4743-B4A8-74D1DB3FD8A4" />

        <!--  Site  Publish features -->
        <Feature ID="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" />

      </WebFeatures>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
  <Modules>

    <Module Name="DefaultBlank" Url="">
      <File Url="default.aspx">
         <View List="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Folder;" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="Left" />
      </File>
    </Module>
</Modules>
</Project>
```

Once the site is created its an empty publishing page. There is no webpart added. When I remove the publising features from the onet.xml and create a new site I do get the webparts, but its not a publishing page

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 ways that you can add a web part to a page layout.  There may be other and more efficent and correct ways.  But these are the ones I have found.  Hopefully they will point you in the right direction.

- Statically adding them to the page layout.  This method prevents access to the edit controls when you edit the page.  If can only be modified in the VS project.
- Declaratively add it to the elements.xml for the page layout. This will allow the web part to be modified.  But has the following problems.

  - When the project is deployed a new instance of the web part is added the web part zone.  The old instances of the web part need to be deleted using a FeatureActivated Event receiver
  - If changes are made the the web part in VS.  These changes will only apply to new instances of the page layout.

The code for option 2 is below.  This code may need to be tested and tweaked and settings changed to meet your project.

On the page layout file create your web part zone

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone ID="SearchWebPartZone" runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" />
```

In the elements add the web part declaratively AllUsersWebPart element.  Make sure you wrap up the web part declaration with CDATA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="PageLayouts" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
      <File Path="PageLayouts\yourPageLayout.aspx" Url="PageLayouts/yourPageLayout.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="Title" Value="Page Layout" />
        <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="page Layout" />
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
        <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#Page Layout Content type;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39000a866239b6e549198be805856fbb8101000ec0ecc41784476280021f6e9105c089" />
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="SearchWebPartZone" WebPartOrder="0">
          <![CDATA[
            <WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
            <Title>Search Box</Title>
            <Description>Displays a search box that allows users to search for information.</Description>
            <FrameType>None</FrameType>
            <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
            <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
            <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
            <GoImageUrl xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">/_layouts/images/gosearch15.png</GoImageUrl>
            <GoImageUrlRTL xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">/_layouts/images/gosearchrtl15.png</GoImageUrlRTL>
            <GoImageActiveUrl xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">/_layouts/images/gosearchhover15.png</GoImageActiveUrl>
            <GoImageActiveUrlRTL xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">/_layouts/images/gosearchrtlhover15.png</GoImageActiveUrlRTL>
            <DropDownModeEx xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:SearchBoxEx">HideScopeDD_DefaultContextual</DropDownModeEx>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx</TypeName>
          </WebPart>       
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

A sample of the code for the Event receiver

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
        {
            SPList list = site.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;

            // find the right Page Layout
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                if (item.Name.Equals("yourPageLayout.aspx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    SPFile file = item.File;
                    file.CheckOut();
                    try
                    {
                        // get the Web Part Manager for the Page Layout
                        SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

                        // iterate through all Web Parts and remove duplicates
                        while (wpm.WebParts.Count > 1)
                        {
                            System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp = wpm.WebParts[0];
                            wpm.DeleteWebPart(wp);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        file.Update();

                        if (file.Level == SPFileLevel.Checkout)
                        {
                            file.CheckIn("Feature Activated Event Receiver to remove duplicate Webparts");

                            if (list.EnableMinorVersions)
                            {
                                file.Publish("Feature Activated Event Receiver Published");
                            }

                            if (list.EnableModeration)
                            {
                                file.Approve("Feature Activated Event Receiver Approve");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```